# How to make sure that sessionStorage with two different functions does not interfere with each other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wrote a simple jquery script that increases `font-size` by certain percentages for each element on the page. I managed to save its result in sessionStorage, so after refreshing the page I have saved the result of the script. The problem occurs when I added a second script increasing `font-size` by another value. I used the same approach to save the value in sessionStorage as for the first script, but unfortunately both together do not work as they should. When I save the value of the first one, I run the second script and then refresh the page, then I save the result of the first script. How to make both of them work together without collision ?

JQuery code:

```
$('.normal-size').click(function(){
    $('html').each(function(){
        $(this).css("fontSize", "100%");
    });
});

const biggerFontSize = sessionStorage.getItem("biggerFonts");
if(biggerFontSize == "true"){
    sessionStorage.removeItem("largestFonts");
    $('html').each(function(){
        $(this).css("fontSize", "125%");
    });
}

$('.bigger-size').click(function(){
    $('html').each(function(){
        $(this).css("fontSize", "125%");
        sessionStorage.setItem("biggerFonts", "true");
    });
});

const largestFontSize = sessionStorage.getItem("largestFonts");
if(largestFontSize == "true"){
    sessionStorage.removeItem("biggerFonts");
    $('html').each(function(){
        $(this).css("fontSize", "150%");
    });
}

$('.largest-size').click(function(){
    $('html').each(function(){
        $(this).css("fontSize", "150%");
        sessionStorage.setItem("largestFonts", "true");
    });
});
```

My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nsog8sm43x/9zfnep4d/3/

Comment: Why not just have a single key named "fontSize" that you store the font size in? If it's empty, you set it to `100%`.

Comment: You mean one key instead of two "bigFonts" and "biggerFonts", right ?

Comment: Yes, it seems like what you're really interested in knowing is what size the user wants their fonts to be.

Comment: That's right. The user selects the size and his selection is to be saved in the browser. You just have to take into account that the user can change it several times by choosing the right one. Unfortunately my script saves only first choice.

Comment: Okay, I changed the key everywhere to the same key, but without a positive result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single key for `fontSize`, and a single function for setting the font size. Then your button logic becomes very simple, as does the initial setting of the font size on page load.

```js
function setFontSize(size) {
  if (size != null && size.length) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("fontSize", size);
    $('html').each(function() {
      $(this).css("fontSize", size);
    });
  }
}

// on page load, get the font size from sessionStorage and set it
const fontSize = sessionStorage.getItem("fontSize");
setFontSize(fontSize);

$('.normal-size').click(function() {
  setFontSize("100%");
});

$('.bigger-size').click(function() {
  setFontSize("125%");
});

$('.largest-size').click(function() {
  setFontSize("150%");
});
```

[Here's an updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv78ug6y/).

Answer (score 0):

you need add single session storage key for update the value based on your selection like this.

```js
 const fontSize = sessionStorage.getItem("fontSize");
        
if (fontSize == "normal") {
  $('html').each(function() {
    $(this).css("fontSize", "100%");
  });
}

$('.normal-size').click(function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("fontSize", "normal");
  $('html').each(function() {
    $(this).css("fontSize", "100%");
  });
});

if (fontSize == "bigger") {
  $('html').each(function() {
    $(this).css("fontSize", "125%");
  });
}

$('.bigger-size').click(function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("fontSize", "bigger");
  $('html').each(function() {
    $(this).css("fontSize", "125%");

  });
});

if (fontSize == "larger") {
  $('html').each(function() {
    $(this).css("fontSize", "150%");
  });
}

$('.largest-size').click(function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("fontSize", "larger");
  $('html').each(function() {
    $(this).css("fontSize", "150%");
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that Stack Snippets are sandboxed and don't allow the use of `sessionStorage`.